# Definition of a sheaf

Tags: manifolds, superalgebra, supergeometry, supermanifolds

Can someone give me a strict defenition of a constant sheaf. And I need a nice reference for supermanifolds.

Second, concerning the commutation of the pullbacks with the restrictions, how cna I check that in the special case where each of the sheaves is a subsheaf of the sheaf of continuous functions, then the commutation is indeed satisfied.

Comment: You mean the general definition of a sheaf? Like a functor $F:\mathcal{C} \to \text{Set}^{\text{op}}$? Then a constant sheaf would be a sheaf that factorizes through the one element category?

Comment: I know that a sheaf is a presheaf with additional properties, and the presheaf is a contravariant functor, but haw can I define the constant sheaf or constant presheaf. Thank you

Comment: I edited my comment if you want

Comment: Please can you clarify to me what you mean. I need a strict defenition.

Comment: @JulesBesson That's the definition of a pre-sheaf.

Comment: A constant presheaf $F$ would be a pre sheaf fr which it exists two functors $G:C \to 1$ $H:1 \to \text{Set}^{\text{op}}$ with $1 = 1^{\text{op}}$ the category with one element and one morphism given by the identity, such that $F = H \circ G$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I know I did not want to have a super long comment

Comment: @MousaHamieh Your title says you want the definition of a sheaf, and your body says you want the definition of a constant sheaf. Did you want both?

Comment: Thank you so much. I happy that you give me the desired answer. Could post a good reference about sheaf and category of ringed spaces and elementary theory of supermanifolds.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, I need both if you can provide.

Comment: But I'm not sure that every sheaf commutes with pullbacks...

Comment: @julesBesson If we have to topological space X, Y and (X, \mathcal{O} _X), (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y) there respective renged spaces, then  a morphism from between these two ringed spaces is a pair (f, f^*) where f is contenous function from X to Y, and f^* is a pull back from \mathcal{O} _Y to \mathcal {O} _X. That is a collection of ring homomorphism. \mathcal{O} _Y(V) to \mathcal{O}_X(f^-1(V)), V is open subset of Y, that commute with restrictions.

Comment: Put both in the question, or readers don't know if you want two things or just made an error. The title is not the question, and the question should be complete.